# Local declaration of 'ActionSheet' hides instance variable

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactionsheet

Getting three warning messages for these three statements

```
ActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;

[ActionSheet showInView:self.view ];

[ActionSheet release];
```

Local declaration of 'ActionSheet' hides instance variable

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActionSheet *ActionSheet;

@synthesize ActionSheet;


-(void)displayActionSheet:(id)sender

{

UIActionSheet *ActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Language Options"
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Devanagari", @"English", nil];

ActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;

[ActionSheet showInView:self.view ];

[ActionSheet release];

}
```

Any idea what is wrong.

Comment: post please your header file info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: variables are NOT written in uppercase. please rename your actionSheet variable.

Second: your property hast the same name, as your local variable (ActionSheet in your case). If you want to save the actionSheet in the member variable, than remove `UIActionSheet*` resulting in that function:

```
-(void)displayActionSheet:(id)sender
{
    ActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"Language Options"
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Devanagari", @"English", nil];
    ActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [ActionSheet showInView:self.view ];
    [ActionSheet release];
}
```